# Solidus / Spree + Override checkout controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, overriding, e-commerce, spree

I am working on my RoR4 app with the [Solidus](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus) gem included. When I tried to override its frontend's **checkout_controller#update** method (located [here](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/blob/master/frontend/app/controllers/spree/checkout_controller.rb)).

I override the controller according to [Spree's documents](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/logic.html), but it gave me an error of `uninitialized constant OrderUpdateAttributes`.

`CheckoutController#update` named as `/app/controllers/spree/checkout_controller_decorator.rb`

```
Spree::CheckoutController.class_eval do
  def update
   if OrderUpdateAttributes.new(@order, update_params, request_env: request.headers.env).apply
     @order.temporary_address = !params[:save_user_address]
     success = if @order.state == 'confirm'
        @order.complete
     else
        @order.next
     end
     if !success
       flash[:error] = @order.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
       redirect_to(checkout_state_path(@order.state)) && return
     end

     if @order.completed?
       @current_order = nil
       flash.notice = Spree.t(:order_processed_successfully)
       flash['order_completed'] = true
       redirect_to completion_route
     else
       redirect_to checkout_state_path(@order.state)
     end
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

I needed to override this method in order to execute some action after an order is completed (after its checkout). Is there something I am missing to cause this error? Or another way to execute the action?

Answer (score 1):

I figured the best way to handle this situation is to use the state machine at the model level. For this action, more documentation can be found [here](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/orders.html#the-order-state-machine), and more precisely to use the decorator to override on the core's `order` model, located on `core/app/models/spree/order.rb`.